# Can I use memory after pointer deinitialization?

Tags: swift, pointers, memory

Can I use memory after pointer deinitialization?

e.g.

```
let q = UnsafeMutablePointer<Float>.allocate(capacity: 1)
q.pointee = 123.125
let bq = UnsafeRawBufferPointer(start: q.deinitialize(count: 1), count: 4) // (*)
for i in bq.reversed() {
    print(String(i, radix: 16), terminator: " ")
}

q.deallocate()
print()
```

It's my core solution of this task: https://pl.spoj.com/problems/PP0504D/

Problem in the task is simple: Write a function which show representation of machine bytes of Float value.

`float2bytes(123.125) prints 42 f6 40 0` 
But that is not the crux of the problem.

***I'm not deeply in pointers. My doubt is: May I use memory after deinitialization which is points by another pointer (this memory is NOT deallocated)? What does deinitialization really mean?***

```
let p = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>.allocate(capacity: 1)
p.initialize(to: 7)
print(p.pointee)
p.initialize(to: 9)
p.deinitialize(count: 1)
// something may crash the memory in this place?
print(p.pointee)
p.deallocate()
```

Anyone can show me the code that causes the crash after `deinicialize(count:)` ?

Comment: You need to explain the problem you are trying to solve in English, since the language of SO is English and the linked problem is in Polish.

Comment: I corrected my post

Answer (score 3):

Pointers are not deinitialized. Memory is. When you call `q.deinitialize(count: 1)`, you have deinitialized the memory pointed to by `q`. It is invalid to then read deinitialized memory. It'll almost certainly "work" because this is a trivial type (a float), but it's not valid.

Memory has more states than "allocated" and "deallocated." It also needs to be bound and initialized. When you call `deinitialize`, the memory is put back into the uninitialized state (but still bound), but it must be reinitialized before reading.

For the full details, see [Safely manage pointers in Swift](https://wwdc.io/share/wwdc20/10167) from WWDC 2020.

For the specific case you're describing, you don't need memory management. You can ask the system for the bytes of a value directly:

```
let value: Float = 123.125

withUnsafeBytes(of: value) { q in
    for i in q.reversed() {
        print(String(i, radix: 16), terminator: " ")
    }
}
```

(I understand you may have some other problem you're solving. But this is how you'd do what you've described.)

To your second example, you probably would never see a crash from that (since Float is trivial). But its behavior is undefined. Once you invoke undefined behavior, you may be very surprised at the optimizations the compiler is allowed to apply. This could, for example, print nothing, or print some constant value. Or it could crash (probably not, but it could). Or it could work perfectly, but still be wrong.

Comment: I always [wished](https://forums.swift.org/t/withunsafetypepunnedpointer/14540/11) there was a simple state graph in the docs that I could refer to when working with the pointer APIs. I always find myself referring back to that video, but it's so costly to search through it to find the part I need, and I never built a good confidence/understanding in my solutions :/

Comment: It is very frustrating that the only documentation for many parts of the system is WWDC videos, and that they often take them down after a few years.

Answer (score 1):

While @RobNapier's answer is certainly correct, you can also access the “raw bits” of a `Float` using its `bitPattern` property:

```
let f: Float = 123.125
let bits = f.bitPattern
```

You can then chop up the bits into bytes:

```
let bytesLittleEndian = stride(from: 0, to: UInt32.bitWidth, by: 8)
    .map { UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: bits >> $0) }

let bytesBigEndian = stride(from: 0, to: UInt32.bitWidth, by: 8)
    .reversed()
    .map { UInt8(truncatingIfNeeded: bits >> $0) }
```

Comment: Note that this is not exactly the "raw bits." `bitPattern` is defined to return the IEEE 754 binary interchange format, which I expect is usually going to be what's in memory, but it's not promised to be identical. (There might be different normalization, for example, though I wouldn't be surprised if that never happens in practice.) `withUnsafePointer(to:)` could return something different. (But you definitely *should* use `bitPattern` for anything that you'd want "the bits" for. Agreed! That would be better than my answer for practical uses.)

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to Rob Napier for this explenation. When I didn't know the pointers yet, I solved the problem like this:

```
import Foundation

let k = Int(readLine()!)!

for _ in 1...k {
    let n = String(Float(readLine()!
    .trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces))!
    .bitPattern, radix: 16)
    let f = ((n + repeatElement("0", count: 8 - n.count))
        .reduce("") {
             "\($0)" + "\(($0.count + 1) % 3 == 0 ? "'" : "")" + "\($1)"
     } as String)
        .split(separator: "'")
    .map {
         $0 == "00" ? "0" : $0
     }
    .reduce("") {
         "\($0)\($1) "
    }
    print(f)
}
```

But now I'm wondering how to write UI Test for the code

```
//file
import Foundation

let k = Float(readLine()!)!
print(k)
```

Comment: You should post this on codereview.stackexchange.com There's a lllllot of improvements to be made here